# How to solve the error "Pemission denied" when writing to a NFS shared folder

Tags: debian, ubuntu, nfs, proxmox

I set up my NFS following [this video from Jay (The Linux Guy)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Na_jKeVWzrc) until before setting up the autofs.

In my case my server (192.168.1.99) is running the Proxmox 8 (based on Debian) and my laptop (192.168.1.8) is running Ubuntu 22.04.

After mounting the shared folder in my laptop, I get this error when I try to write to a file:

```
$ echo 'from laptop' >> /mnt/nfs/local/message.txt
bash: /mnt/nfs/local/message.txt: Permission denied
```

this is my `/etc/exports` file on the server:

```
/srv/local 192.168.0.0/255.255.254.0(rw,no_subtree_check)
```

I mounted the folder on my laptop using the command below:

```
$ sudo mount 192.168.1.99:/srv/local /mnt/nfs/local
```

Does anybody know how can I solve this error? I want this shared folder to be writable for anyone.

Comment: what are the owner/group/permissions of `/srv/local` - in my case, I use `all_squash` as well, but that may not be what you want

Comment: `root` `root` are the owners. I'm new on Linux so, to clarify, your setup has `anon` user as the owner and, since the share uses `all_squash`, any user trying to access the folder will be changed to `anon` then having permission to write to the folder.
Am I correct about what to expect?

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment but its a bit long.

You are jumping straight in to provisioning some capability wihtout understanding the tools you are using - although actually using the tools is the best way to learn. But doing a little bit of reading first is always a good idea. There are plenty of introductory articles to Unix/Linux permissions on the internet. e.g. [https://mason.gmu.edu/~montecin/UNIXpermiss.htm](https://mason.gmu.edu/%7Emontecin/UNIXpermiss.htm)

There are pemissions on the clients filesystem up to the mountpoint, thereafter the permissions on the server apply. The permissions (e.g. -rwx-r-x-r--) are associated with a user id and group id (both numeric) these are mapped to a user NAME via /etc/passwd. Your NFS client and NFS server may have different mappings in their respective /etc/passwd file. NFSv4 has mechanisms to work around this if you configure them.

In the comments, you seem to suggest you are using all_squash - however this is NOT shown in the line you quoted from your /etc/exports.

The squash options allow simple mapping of user ids across the NFS mount boundary.

> /mnt/nfs/local/message.txt: Permission denied

To write this file, your UID needs:

- read and execute permissions for /mnt, /mnt/nfs
- read write and execute permissions for /mnt/nfs/local
- write permissions for /mnt/nfs/local/message.txt if it already exists

(and the NFS filesystem needs to be mounted read/write - it can revert to RO under certain error conditions even though you mounted it using the defaults - rw).

@Jaromanda asked for the owner/ group and permissions for /srv/local. I presume your answer was that the owner was root and the group was root - but you didn't say what the permissions were. You neeed to look at the owner, group AND PERMISSIONS of each node in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was permissions for others on the shared folder (`/srv/nfs/local`).

For some reason, this wasn´t an issue during Jay's video. Maybe because he was using Ubuntu and Ubuntu Server and I'm using Ubuntu and Proxmox (which is Debian based)

To solve my issue, I had to rely on [ACL](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists).

Firstly I had to install `acl` in my server (Proxmox 8):

```
apt install acl
```

Then I had run the following command (still on the server):

```
setfacl -PRdm o::rw /srv/local
```

You can read about each of the arguments used in this command [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/new-files-dirs-default-permission#3-setting-the-permissions-with-setfacl).

This command changed the default sharing on `/srv/local` to allow read and write to any other user different from the user and the group of the folder.

My user in my laptop is an **other** user for Proxmox system and now I can write to the shared folder from my laptop.

Thanks to @jaromanda-x and @symcbean for the inputs.